# checking a value against a file python

Tags: iteration, file-handling

I'm not an expert or anything just a beginner but I'm having problems checking a value to see if it's correct against a file, this is my code right now

```
line = open("question.txt", "r").readlines()[0]
secondline = open("answer.txt", "r").readlines()[0]
print("Please enter A or B for the correct answer")
answer = input("What does "+ line + " mean? \n A: set of rules \n B: a 
program ").upper()
if answer == (secondline):
    print("Well done")
else:
    print("incorrect")
```

---

```
what outputs is: 
Please enter A or B for the correct answer
What does algorithm mean? 
A: set of rules 
B: a program a
incorrect
>>>
```

the 'question' text file only consists of algorithm on the first line
and the 'answer' text file only has 'a' on the first line.

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To make this code work you can either replace `upper()` with `lower()`, or change the content of answer.txt to `A`.